# How to find a ray that intersects a polygon minimum times?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

Let P be a simple, but not necessarily convex, polygon and q an arbitrary
point not necessarily in P.

Design an efficient algorithm to find a line segment originating from q that intersects the minimum number of edges of P.

Comment: Sure `min(line_segment) = Line(q, q)`.  I suspect you haven't told us all of the requirements though.

Comment: looks like a homework question

Comment: well, interesting problem, but nobody here likes questions of the sort this is the problem, SO do something bout it.

Comment: If you don't know how to solve a homework, try to sort data first (here sort vertices by polar angle relative to point given)

Answer (score 0):

If `q` is your point in the space of 2D, we can write `q(x,y)`. We know that a polyhedron have the edges(E), vertices(V)  and  faces(F) which all of this terms are related with the formula `V - E + F = 2` from the Euler's theorem but the problem turns out to be easier since it is for a polygon.

So the plain is to find an edge and calcule the direction vector of the point `q(x,y)` to the center of the edge, doing this (and if the polygon is convex) we are sure that this line segment will only goes through one edge of P.

The calculation will need a little of linear algebra, but it is not that difficult, for example:

**1 -** Find the distance from a line to a point (so we can find the closest edge to use in this problem):

[image]

**2 -** Also, a good idea would be to find the point on this line which is closest to `(x0,y0)` has coordinates:

[image]

*Where the equation of the line is `ax + by + c = 0` and the `(x0,y0)` is an arbitrary point not necessarily in P.*

So, now we can find the point `k(x,y)` on the line that is closest to the initial point `q(x0,y0)`, doing `|q-k| = d`. Where d is the distance that we just calculate. After that you already have everything that you need to *find a line segment originating from q that intersects the minimum number of edges of P.*

**Some places where you can study and find more about this topic:**

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

[mathwords](http://www.mathwords.com/d/distance_point_to_line.htm)

Comment: @NiklasB. "but not necessarily convex", that is what he said, so it can be convex, and into this particular case, my solution will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Think of doing this on a map, so you can think of directions like North, South, East, West, and bearings.

If you have a ray going in a particular direction from q out to infinity, whether it intersects a line between points A and B depends only on the bearing of the ray, and the bearings from q to A and B: if the bearing of the ray is within the range spanned by the bearing from q to A and the bearing from q to B, taking this in the direction of the line, then the ray will intersect the line.

So you can reduce this to a simpler problem. Imagine that all the points are in a circle around q, and the lines are arcs of this circle. Now you need to find a point on this circle which is overlapped by the minimum number of arcs. You will also make life very much easier if you divide each arc that spans 0 degrees into two at 0, cutting e.g. an arc from 320 degrees round to 40 degrees into one from 320 degrees to 360=0 degrees, and one from 0 degrees to 40 degrees.

Good candidate points for this are points just clockwise of each point in the circle. Now order each arc so that it is from a low angle to a high angle, sort the arcs by low angle, and work through them in order, incrementing a counter when you see the start of an arc, and decrementing it when you see the end of an arc (you don't need to worry about arcs that wrap across 0=360 degrees because you have just made sure that there aren't any). The point you want to find is the one associated with the smallest value of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Taking `q` as the origin of the coordinates, compute the polar arguments of the vertices. This is done in linear time.

Then every edge spans an interval of angles. To handle the wraparound, you can split the intervals that cross the 360° border.

You turned the problem in an instance of 1D intervals overlap. This is readily solved in `O(N Log(N))` time.